# How to tell when Mediaplayer has finished playing audio

Tags: java, javafx

I have a boolean for when the music stops playing,

```
mediaPlayer.getStatus().equals(Status.PLAYING);
```

The issue is, when the song finishes playing, it still thinks its playing. On android there is a OnCompletionListener(). I was wondering if there was something similar on PC.

I'm using the Mediaplayer from JavaFX

Comment: Are you referring to JavaFX's `MediaPlayer`? How are we supposed to know which media player you're referring to? Also, you could always check out the JavaDoc for the type you're questioning about, if they exist.

Comment: `getStatus` returns the current state of the `status` property, which means unless you're repeatedly evaluating this or unless you're doing the check from a listener to the `status` property, you only get the results for the initial `getStatus` call...

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`onEndOfMedia()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/media/MediaPlayer.html#onEndOfMediaProperty) hook.

> Event handler invoked when the player currentTime reaches a media marker.

```
 player.setOnEndOfMedia(() -> {
      // Your logic here
 });
```

Comment: Depending on what the OP needs, he/she may need `setOnStopped()` instead. Good to let OP know so that he/she can decide on his/her own what is more suitable.